# $\sigma$-closed forcing notions add a $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $\mathcal{D}$?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Say that a forcing $\mathbb{P}$ is $\sigma$-closed if, for any decreasing sequence
$\langle p_n : n \in\omega\rangle$ in P, there is some $q \in \mathbb{P}$ such that $q \leq p_n$ for all $n\in\omega$.

If $\mathbb{P}$ is $\sigma$-closed and $\mathcal{D}$ is a family of dense subsets $|\mathcal{D}|\leq\aleph_1$, then there exists  a $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $\mathcal{D}$?

I know, if $\mathbb{P}$ is any notion forcing and $\mathcal{D}$ is a family of dense subsets and $\mathcal{D}:=\langle D_n:n<\omega\rangle$ is countable. We can find a sequence $\langle p_n:n<\omega\rangle$ such that $p_0:=p$, $p_{n+1}\leq p_n$ and $p_n\in D_n$, so set 
$G:=\{p\in\mathbb{P}:\exists n<\omega(p_n\leq p)\}$ work

I dont use the fact that $\mathbb{P}$ is $\sigma$-closed.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Do you know how to show that for any forcing $\mathbb P$ and any countable family $\mathcal D$ of dense sets there is a $\mathbb P$-generic for $\mathcal D$?

Comment: In much the same way as for countable $\mathcal D.$ Only at limit stages you will need closedness.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the argument, but $p$ is still used in two ways, making it ambiguous, and there is a small indexing problem. My suggestion is to replace $p_0=p$ at the beginning with $p_0\in D_0$.

Comment: The argument where you saw them start with a given initial element called $p$ was to show that you can additionally arrange that the generic filter include some arbitrary $p\in\mathbb P.$ You can get rid of it as Andrés suggested, or keep it in for the slightly stronger result and deal with the annoyance that it throws the indexing off by one. Note that you can also start the sequence with an arbitrary $p$ in the same way in the uncountable case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal D = \{D_\alpha : \alpha <\omega_1\}.$ Recursively construct a decreasing sequence $\langle p_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ such that $p_\alpha\in D_\alpha.$ The successor stages work just like in the countable case. At a limit stage $\lambda$ take some sequence $\alpha_n$ cofinal in $\lambda$ of type $\omega$ and then use $\sigma$-closedness to get a $q\le p_{\alpha_n}$ for all $n,$ then take $p_\lambda \le q$ such that $p_\lambda \in D_\lambda.$ Like in the countable case, the $p_\alpha$ generate a filter, which is generic by construction.